# Does rice protein have a high concentration of arsenic?

Tags: food-chemistry

According to recent reports rice is high in arsenic. What about rice protein?

I am taking a protein powder that has "yellow pea protein isolate, sprouted whole-grain rice protein concentrate, organic instantized quinoa seed protein, organic Chia Sprout protein".

Would protein concentrate from Rice have high levels of arsenic?

http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine/2015/01/how-much-arsenic-is-in-your-rice/index.htm

Comment: *sigh* Rice doesn't inherently have any arsenic at all. There may be a bit in one sample, a bit more in another. In theory there could be none whatsoever. This question is quite bad for a one which was upvoted 6 times and isn't HNQ.

Comment: To the contrary, I'd say arsenic is ubiquitous in soils worldwide and that every plant contains arsenic, it's just a matter of how much. If you don't measure any it's because your instrumentation doesn't have a low enough detection limit, not because the plant doesn't have any arsenic at all. That's true for about any element, but arsenic is a particularly big concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The US FDA [reported](https://www.fda.gov/downloads/food/foodborneillnesscontaminants/metals/ucm352467.pdf) arsenic testing of 12 rice protein powders as follows:

> 333863609,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Plant-Based Energizer:
>   **0.1**
>
> 333511892,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Protein Energizer:
>   **0.8**
>
> 333511937,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Protein Energizer:
>   **0.9**
>
> 334620956,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Raw Vegan Chocolate:
>   **0.9**
>
> 334094485,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders
>   Plant-Based Drink Mix:
>   **1.0**
>
> 333511880,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Raw Protein:
>   **1.1**
>
> 333687971,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   High Protein Energy Meal:
>   **1.4**
>
> 333687931,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   High Protein Energy Meal:
>   **1.6**
>
> 334093871,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Blend of protein, fruits & veggies:
>   **1.6**
>
> 334094067,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Chocolate Plant Protein Shake:
>   **3.7**
>
> 334093956,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Blend of protein, fruits & veggies:
>   **4.4**
>
> 333688312,
>   Dietary Supplements,
>   Rice Protein Powders,
>   Organic Meal Replacement:
>   **5.7**

Where the units are micrograms of inorganic arsenic per serving.

Comment: Thanks, So to cut to the chase, does rice protien have high levels of arsenic? Took a look at the link but looks like it requires a more concentrated sitting to understand. How many units of inorganic arsenic per serving is too high?

Comment: @larry909 well the FDA proposed an action level of 100 ppb inorganic arsenic for infants cereal https://www.fda.gov/food/foodborneillnesscontaminants/metals/ucm319870.htm and 1 of the 12 samples above exceeded that level.

Comment: Which one? How many micrograms equals 100 pbb?

Comment: @larry909 "Blend of protein, fruits & veggies" was 152 ppb of inorganic arsenic (230 ppb total arsenic). It was  4.4 micrograms of inorganic arsenic for a 29 gram serving.  (see page 58 of the pdf in the answer).

Comment: So in general, based on your understanding of these numbers, does rice protien powder have a higher level of arsenic per serving than a serving of regular rice? About the same?

Comment: @larry909 on average the rice protein powder had about half as much inorganic arsenic per serving as the rice.

Comment: To add some more context from ConsumerLab.com: "The cancer-warning threshold of the State of California is 10 mcg of arsenic per daily serving, meaning that if someone consumed more than one serving of some of these products in one day, they could exceed this amount."